# How can I "mask" the url using .htaccess in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been playing around with this for a while, but I'm still not sure if this is even possible.

I want a url to point to a different location on my webserver, but not change the url in the address bar.

Ex:

**tp.test.com would access test.com/tp/hi**

and subsequent urls:

**tp.test.com/foo would point to test.com/tp/hi/foo**

Ive been trying to achieve this using RewriteCond and RewriteRule and playing around with the flags for RewriteRule but haven't had any success at all.

**Edit:**
This is what I had tried...

`RewriteRule ^tp.test.com/blog/$ http://tp.test.com/tp/hi/$1 [r=301,L]`

Comment: Please post what you already tried using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi%{REQUEST_URI} -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tp/hi/$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT:

Since you have to be explicit about what you *actually* want in the URI, the above isn't going to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi/%1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tp/hi/%1 -l
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /tp/hi/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What if i wanted tp.test.com/blog/ to be masked as well? Is this close? RewriteRule ^tp.test.com/blog/(.*)$ /tp/hi/$1 [L]

Comment: @890123 No, if `tp.test.com` is a hostname, it will never be used in the string sent to the rewrite engine. You can't match a hostname in a rewrite rule.

Comment: That makes sense. Would the solution be to add this above the rewriterule? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tp\.test\.com How would my redirectRule change to handle the /blog/ subdirectory?

Comment: @890123 `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /tp/hi/$1 [L]`, just without the hostname and without a leading slash.

Comment: @890123 No, just changing that line without changing the rest of the conditions won't work. You're asking a completely different question by suddenly saying a `/blog/` needs to be in the URI, therefore, my answer to your original question isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for changing the question halfway through